# How to make text and table in the same level?

Tags: minipage, tabularx, text

I have a text and a table and it should be on the same level. Right now I have a table and a text below it. How to make it correctly? create a table and than hide borders of the left column?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.27\textwidth}
\medskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X |  }
\hline
Табельний номер \\  \hline
0000000000000  \\  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}

\noindent Прийняти на роботу з \underline{25.01.2016} \\
\indent \hspace{2.7cm} до \underline{25.01.2017} \\

\end{document}
```

Here is what I want to have:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\noindent 
\begin{tabular}[t]{ | l |  }\firsthline
    Табельний номер \\  \hline
    0000000000000  \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r}
Прийняти на роботу з \underline{25.01.2016} \\
 до \underline{25.01.2017} 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to add space between these tables? How to make that one part be on the left side of the page, and another on the right?

Comment: for  the first tabular use `\end{tabular}\hfill` or instead of `\hfill` a length `\hspace{...}`

Answer (score 2):

You can put the `minipage` in a `figure` environement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.27\textwidth}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X |  }
\hline
Табельний номер \\  \hline
0000000000000  \\  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}
\medskip
Прийняти на роботу з \underline{25.01.2016} \\
\indent \hspace{2.7cm} до \underline{25.01.2017} \\
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: when I'm inserting this code in my document it appears in the top of the document, fow to put this figure in the middle of the document?

Comment: @Lucky_girl You can write `\begin{figure*}[h]`